# Animator can't animate sprite property on SpriteMak

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created an animation that should change the property "Sprite" on a SpriteMask component. I tried recording the change in the animation windows, but the property was not recorded (every other property was recorded when changed). I also tried adding manually the property in the animation windows clicking in the "Add Property" button, but the Sprite Mask doesn't show the Sprite property (only shows Enabled, Mask Alpha, some Materials properties and Sorting Order).

I've looked for informations regarded this issue but could find any. Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got same problem and nobody talking about this...
So I solved it by making this simple code.

But remember to I didn't test well this script.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteMask))]
public class SpriteMaskOverrider : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField, Tooltip("Use this field to control mask's sprite via animation instead SpriteMask.sprite.")]
    Sprite sprite;

    SpriteMask mask;


#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if(mask == null)
            Start();

        Update();
    }
#endif

    private void Start()
    {
        TryGetComponent(out mask);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(mask != null)
            mask.sprite = sprite;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).